# How to get HtmlDocument & active HtmlElementd from default web browser

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim webBrowser1 As Object = New WebBrowser
webBrowser1 = Process.Start(MemSite(CurrCell), ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized)
Dim HtmlDoc As HtmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document
Dim htmlElem As HtmlElement = HtmlDoc.All.Item(0)
If htmlElem.TagName = "HTML" Then

End If
```

- Trying to get Active elements from default web browser without using
  form layout + Web Browser Control.
  and post the username + password.

Comment: Please try to be more specific what you are trying to achieve. To me it seem that you want to iterate through a page HTML elements and find and fill Username and  Password texboxes. It this is so the question seems to be too broad and on the way to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** What you are trying to achieve is not possible.

**Long answer:**
Each web browser has its own way of managing the HTML DOM. There isn't a universal solution that'll work for all of them.

The only way this can be done is if you get ahold of an API for each web browser you want to target, and then decide which API to use based on which the user has installed as his/her default. Doing so will require **A LOT** of time and effort, but it is *technically* possible (assuming the browsers you want to target have a public API that can be used for automation).

Comment: Where can I find the API's ?

Comment: @Alex : As I said you can only do this _**if**_ the browsers that you intend to target each has got an API that supports web automation. I never said they existed. You have to use your favourite search engine and look that up for yourself.